# Openfire установка, создание базы данных

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb, openfire

Устанавливаю `openfire` на `ubuntu 16.04`. `Mysql` версия 15.1, distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB, версия `openfire` 4.5.3. Дошел до шага, где устанавливается база данных, в ее качестве выбрал `MariaDB`. Создал пользователя, дал ему привилегии, подключился к БД. Следующий шаг в БД добавить данные из файла `openfire_mysql.sql` следующей командой:

`source /usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql;`

На этом этапе получаю следующие ошибки

```
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 119 in file: '/usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql': Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 127 in file: '/usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql': Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 143 in file: '/usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql': Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 163 in file: '/usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql': Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 372 in file: '/usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql': Table 'openfire.ofMucService' doesn't exist
```

После чего команда `show tables` не показывает список таблиц, соответственно ничего не выгрузилось. Как с этим бороться?

Comment: Гугль — сила! https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/14529543 подробно разобрано.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Поменяю, как буду у компа значения. Но что мне делать с последней ошибкой?

Comment: Не вижу в вопросе версию `mysql` и `openfire`

Comment: @AndreyMihalev извиняюсь, исправил вопрос

Comment: Ошибка скорее всего в том, что вы делает по какой то инструкции, и там используются `character` который используется не 1 а 3 байта на символ. Копайте в эту сторону на вашей версии mysql

Comment: @AndreyMihalev https://www.dmosk.ru/instruktions.php?object=openfire-ubuntu
вот по этой инструкции делаю, но там вроде как с `character` нет ничего

Comment: @AndreyMihalev и так же последняя ошибка интересует, что с ней делать

Comment: Последняя ошибка, вероятно, возникает в результате возникновения одной из предыдущих.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev так и было, спасибо, сейчас оформлю ответ

Answer (score 1):

Решение было следующим:

Открываю файл, где была обнаружена ошибка:

```
 vi /usr/share/openfire/resources/database/openfire_mysql.sql
```

Нахожу нужные строчки:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ofExtComponentConf (
   subdomain             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
   wildcard              TINYINT         NOT NULL,
   secret                VARCHAR(255),
   permission            VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (subdomain)
);
```

И меняю значение в строчке, на которую ругалось:
`subdomain VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL,`